# How to create a zip file in memory in Android?

Tags: android, arrays, zip

this may seem as a trivial task, but we could not found any working solution for creating a zip file in Android **in memory**. The thing is that we take multiple photos, and create Jpeg from those photos. Then we would like to **zip all** those images and upload them to backend.

Why it is not possible? Does somebody know a working solution?

It is even possible in the web, take a look:

https://github.com/Stuk/jszip

Comment: You are likely to run out of memory doing all the things that you describe, given Android's heap limits.

Comment: Why when web browser enables such functionality? It works well on Android phones, too. I would handle that exception, myself.